# How do I show this :$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} x^n 2\cosh( x)e^{-x^2}=0$ if it is true with $n$ odd positive integer?

Tags: integration, hyperbolic-functions, orthogonal-polynomials, error-function

I have looked to show that this integral:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} x^n 2\cosh( x)e^{-x^2}=0$$

for  $n$ is an odd positive integer , but i don't succeed to show that using standard method for getting closed form , Wolfram alpha show that is $0$ for some odd positive integer as shown [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral(2(x%5E3)cosh+x+e%5E(-x%C2%B2))),+x%3D-+infty+to+%2B+infty)  for $n=3$ , then my question here is :

**Question :** How do I show that integral is $0$ for odd positive integer $n$ if it is true ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function is odd at this case and makes the integral zero(because of strong exponential term in function equation the integral converges)

Answer (score 0):

The integrand is an odd function in that case, being the product of an odd function, a constant, and two even functions. The integral of an odd function over a symmetric domain is $0$.

Answer (score 0):

The function $f_n$ defined by
$$
f_n\left(x\right)=2x^n\text{cosh}\left(x\right)e^{-x^2}
$$
is odd when $n=2p+1$ ($-f_n\left(x\right)=f_n\left(-x\right)$. Hence
$$
\int_{0}^{+\infty}f_n\left(x\right)\text{d}x=-\int_{-\infty}^{0}f_n\left(x\right)\text{d}x
$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint :** $$\int_{-a}^a f(x) \rm{d} x =0$$ if $f(x)$ is an odd function.